# Особая запись вектора-столбца в LaTeX

Tags: latex, линейная-алгебра

Преподаватель в ВУЗе записывает обозначения векторов-столбцов в виде `|x>`. Есть ли такая запись в LaTeX, кроме, собственно `|x>`?

---

*Прим.: я гуглил, гуглил, да что-то не получилось найти вообще ничего, кроме ответов вида «как записать матрицу / вектор со скобками».*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не `braket` ищете?

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

\[ \bra{x} \]

\[ \ket{y} \]

\[ \braket{x|y} \]

\end{document}
```

[image: Результат.]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ; было бы лучше, если бы вы прикрепили к ответу результат))

Comment: @dimon4ezzz  Добавил.